# Polymer listen to events from child light DOM

Tags: polymer

is it possible for a parent element to listen to events from light DOM children? My setup does not seem to be working.

```
<dom-module id="sm-tabs">
<template>
    <sm-redux-store>
        <button on-click="handleDispatchClick">Dispatch action</button>
    </sm-redux-store>
</template>

<script src="../../dist/tabs.component.js"></script>
</dom-module>
```

I want sm-redux-store to listen to an event that I call from the handleDispatchClick function. Here is the function:

```
const handleDispatchClick = function(e) {
this.fire('dispatch', {
    action: {
        type: 'CHANGE_TEMP',
        newTemp: 'temporary data'
    };
});
};
```

In my script for sm-redux-store, I have this listener object:

```
const listeners = {
    'dispatch': 'handleDispatch'
};
```

sm-redux-store never handles the event raised from the button click, and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just figured out what was wrong. Inside of handleDispatchClick, this is bound to the parent element. The parent element is sm-tabs, not sm-redux-store. I just need to wrap sm-tabs with sm-redux-store outside of the template, and it works.